# How do I make a navbar menu mobile responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have some homework problems, so i needed to make a website for a school project and my menu navbar isn't mobile responsive and I'm not sure how to fix it. Can somebody please help? I'm working with Bootstrap 3 and this is my code.

```js
$(document).ready({
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown() 
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>


      </div>
      <div class="main" id="section1">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar" >
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="Comics.html" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Marvel<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#sp">Spiderman</a></li>
                <li><a href="#im">Iron man</a></li>
                <li><a href="#am">Captain America</a></li>
              </ul>

              <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="Comics.html" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">DC<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#flash">The Flash</a></li>
                <li><a href="#aq">Aquaman</a></li>

              </ul>


                <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="Comics.html" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Books<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="HarryPotter.html">Harry Potter</a></li>
                <li><a href="OneShot.html">One shot</a></li>
                <li><a href="MrMercedes.html">Mr.Mercedes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">More<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="Education.html">Education</a></li>
                <li><a href="Comics.html">Comics</a></li>
                </ul></li>
                 <li><a href="#com">Interesting Comics</a></li>
            </div></div>
</ul></div></nav>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You better start by fixing the HTML markup errors

Answer (score 0):

> **Create A Mobile Navigation Menu**
>
> 1. Step 1) Add HTML:
>
> Example
>
> ```
> <!-- Load an icon library to show a hamburger menu (bars) on small screens -->
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
>
> <!-- Top Navigation Menu -->
> <div class="topnav">
>   <a href="#home" class="active">Logo</a>
>   <!-- Navigation links (hidden by default) -->
>   <div id="myLinks">
>     <a href="#news">News</a>
>     <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
>     <a href="#about">About</a>
>   </div>
>   <!-- "Hamburger menu" / "Bar icon" to toggle the navigation links -->
>   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
>     <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
>   </a>
> </div>
> ```
>
> 2. Step 2) Add CSS:
>
> Example
>
> ```
> /* Style the navigation menu */
> .topnav {
>   overflow: hidden;
>   background-color: #333;
>   position: relative;
> }
>
> /* Hide the links inside the navigation menu (except for logo/home) */
> .topnav #myLinks {
>   display: none;
> }
>
> /* Style navigation menu links */
> .topnav a {
>   color: white;
>   padding: 14px 16px;
>   text-decoration: none;
>   font-size: 17px;
>   display: block;
> }
>
> /* Style the hamburger menu */
> .topnav a.icon {
>   background: black;
>   display: block;
>   position: absolute;
>   right: 0;
>   top: 0;
> }
>
> /* Add a grey background color on mouse-over */
> .topnav a:hover {
>   background-color: #ddd;
>   color: black;
> }
>
> /* Style the active link (or home/logo) */
> .active {
>   background-color: #4CAF50;
>   color: white;
> }
> ```
>
> 3. Step 3) Add JavaScript:
>
> Example
>
> ```
> /* Toggle between showing and hiding the navigation menu links when the user clicks on the hamburger menu / bar icon */
> function myFunction() {
>   var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
>   if (x.style.display === "block") {
>     x.style.display = "none";
>   } else {
>     x.style.display = "block";
>   }
> }
> ```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_mobile_navbar.asp